# Consuming a Webservice and Parsing the XML Data in iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services, parsing, xml-parsing

I am working on a application where my requirement is to consume a webservice and capture the xml data by parsing it. I am not sure about how to consume a webservice and capture the xml data. I am not able to decide which Parser to use to parse the XML. My webservice goes this way "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/test/getTestSchema.cfm?sid=10335&course=ALZ_PATIENT&lesson=991&examtype=R&nStartRow=1&nEndRow=25&videoid=5" . Can anyone please help me out on how to consume a webservice and parse it with a sample code? That would be very helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981700/touchxml-parsing-xml-attributes. You may parse by touch XML Parsing method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We once had used [sudzc](http://sudzc.com/) to consume SOAP based web service in one of our apps. Then used TouchXML to parse the XML returned. It was quite easy and worked very well. sudzc takes WSDL and actually generates code to consume the web service! TouchXML tutorials are abundant on the net.

Comment: sudzc is asking to enter WSDl type. But i am not sure how a WSDl link looks like. My Webservice URL looks like "http://xxxxxxxx/test/getTestSchema.cfm?sid=10335&course=ALZ_PATIENT&lesson=991&examtype=R&nStartRow=1&nEndRow=25&videoid=5" Can u please explain me how to generate the code for the above mentioned URl?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166/Layman-s-SOAP and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soap/index.html?dwzone=ws could be a good starting point.

Comment: SOAP uses XML over http to send request to server. If you are not using SOAP, making a plain http request instead you could use ASIHTTPRequest library for communicating with server and then use some other library to parse the XML. Ofcourse there are other libraries that will fetch and parse data, but I might not be able to comment on their merits/demerits. ASIHTTPRequest worked very well for us. There is ample documentation abt it.